# How to insert an attribute into rspec test for validation messages using i18m

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have my translations file setup with some custom error messages for some ActiveRecord validations, although when I pass an `%{attribute}` into it, the test fails. How do I get the rspec test to use the translation?

en.locale

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        account:
          attributes:
            name:
              invalid: "%{attribute} must only include numbers and letters"
```

rspec test

```
it "is invalid with special characters" do
    account = FactoryGirl.build(:account, name: "test_account_*name")
    account.valid?
    expect(account.errors[:name]).to include(I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.account.attributes.name.invalid'))
  end
```

result

```
    20) Account is invalid with special characters
 Failure/Error: expect(account.errors[:name]).to include(I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.account.attributes.name.invalid'))
   expected ["Name must only include numbers and letters"] to include "%{attribute} must only include numbers and letters"
 # ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to pass `human_attribute_name` of the attribute into the translation as a parameter `attribute`.

The test now passes like this:

```
  it "is invalid with special characters" do
    account = FactoryGirl.build(:account, name: "test_account_*namre")
    account.valid?
    expect(account.errors[:name]).to include(I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.account.attributes.name.invalid', attribute: Account.human_attribute_name(:name)))
  end
```